# Laravel migration ("SQLSTATE[HY000]: error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`orders` 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" please

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

```
 public function up()  {          
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {          
         $table->increments('id');   
         $table->unsignedBigInteger('seller_id');   
         $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('sellers')->onDelete('cascade');   
         $table->decimal('total',8,2);  
         $table->decimal('discount',8,2)->default(0);    
         $table->decimal('tax',8,2);   
         $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);          
         $table->timestamps();  
    }); 
}
```

> sellers table

```
public function up() {  

    Schema::create('sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        
        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('CompanyName');  
        $table->string('SellerName');  
        $table->string('email')->unique();  
        $table->string('password');
        $table->bigInteger('contact');
        $table->mediumText('officeAddress');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });

}
```

I tried all possible ways to define foreign key but couldn't get success please help me out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voSZX.png)

Answer (score 3):

[increments()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-increments)

> The `increments` method creates an auto-incrementing `UNSIGNED INTEGER` equivalent column as a primary key:
>
> ```
> $table->increments('id');
> ```

The `id` column on the `sellers` table is defined using `$table->increments('id');`

The referencing column `seller_id` in the `orders` table **must** have a matching data type.

##### Solution

Orders migration.

```php
 public function up()  {          
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {          
         // ...  
         $table->unsignedInteger('seller_id');   
         // ...
          
    }); 
}
```